# AWS devendpoint Zepelin Notebook no script editor

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, aws-glue

I have this dilemma of making a `.json` file into a file format that needs to be uploaded to AWS Redshift.
I followed these articles to proceed with it:

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/simplify-querying-nested-json-with-the-aws-glue-relationalize-transform/

https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-glue-samples/blob/master/examples/join_and_relationalize.md

As part of the instructions in both articles, `DevEndpoint` notebook must be launched. I was successful to create it however, I am unable to run any queries because I am unable to find any script editor, as seen below.

[Please click to see image of issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ULmss.jpg)

Am I missing any configuration?

I need to transform JSON files and I am not even halfway on it.

Answer (score 0):

How did you set up the dev end point? Is it an AWS Glue provided Dev Endpoint server, or a locally setup notebook?  Can help with your issue if more information is provided.

Anyway, please refer [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/dev-endpoint-tutorial-local-notebook.html)and [setting up zeppelin on windows](https://hernandezpaul.wordpress.com/2016/11/14/apache-zeppelin-installation-on-windows-10/), for any help on setting up local development environment & zeppelin notebook.

Once you set up the zeppelin notebook, have an SSH connection established (using AWS Glue DevEndpoint URL), so you can have access to the data catalog/crawlers,etc., and also the S3 bucket where your data resides.  Then, you can create your python scripts in the zeppelin notebook, and run from the zeppelin.

You can use dev instance provided by Glue, but you may incur additional costs for the same(EC2 instance charges).

Environment settings (updated in response to comments):

```
JAVA_HOME=E:\Java7\jre7
Path=E:\Python27;E:\Python27\Lib;E:\Python27\Scripts;
PYTHONPATH=E:\spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7\python;E:\spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\py4j-0.10.4-src.zip;E:\spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\pys
park.zip
SPARK_HOME=E:\spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7
```

Change the drive name/ folders accordingly.  Let me know if any help neeed.

Regards

Comment: Thanks. I deployed it in AWS Glue to avoid necessary configuration. I tried installing it in my local machine but http://localhost:8080/ says it is service unavailable. What seems to be the problem? thanks!

Comment: Make sure the zeppelin server is started..."Open a command prompt and start Zeppelin executing the zeppelin.cmd in Drive:\ZEPELLIN_DIR\bin\zeppelin.cmd" (for windows).  Once the server is started you should see after a series of console logs, a last line as zeppelin server started, and listening at 8080.  Make sure there is no port conflict for 8080, if so you may need to change the zeppelin port number.

Comment: thank you. I already run it in cmd and already got the message below..
       at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        ... 32 more
 INFO [2018-05-22 12:47:51,426] ({main} AbstractConnector.java[doStart]:266) - S
tarted ServerConnector@2102a4d5{HTTP/1.1}{0.0.0.0:8080}
 INFO [2018-05-22 12:47:51,428] ({main} Server.java[doStart]:379) - Started @292
35ms
 INFO [2018-05-22 12:47:51,429] ({main} ZeppelinServer.java[main]:197) - Done, z
eppelin server started

i tried connecting both 0.0.0.0:8080 and localhost:8080 still with issues..

Comment: Looks like java/spark/hadoop path settings.  See my updated answer for the environment settings, and make sure java is detected.